# Automatically assigning a primary key to an entry in MS-Access via Netbeans

Tags: sql, ms-access, netbeans, primary-key, sql-insert

I am trying to insert values into a table using SQL. A user enters the values except for the primary key which is an autonumber (ID).

```
if (lstCarD.getSelectedIndex() == -1) {
        obj.updateTable("insert into tblSCars values('" + txtBrand.getText() + "','" + txtModel.getText() + "'," + Integer.parseInt(txtSpeed.getText()) + "," + Integer.parseInt(txtWeight.getText()) + "," + Double.parseDouble(txtAcc.getText()) + "," + Integer.parseInt(txtPower.getText()) + ") ");
    } else {
             obj.updateTable("UPDATE tblSCars SET  tblSCars.Brand ='"+ txtBrand.getText()+"','"+ txtModel.getText() + "'," + Integer.parseInt(txtSpeed.getText()) + "," + Integer.parseInt(txtWeight.getText()) + "," + Double.parseDouble(txtAcc.getText()) + "," + Integer.parseInt(txtPower.getText()) +"WHERE RunnerId="+txtBrand.getText());
    }
    pnlStart.setSelectedIndex(2);
    lstSuperCars.clear();
    getCars();
```

Gives me the following error:

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.3.1 row column count mismatch
```

Which can be solved be either allowing the user to enter a field 'ID' or removing the field from the MS-Access Table (works if I do this).

I am trying to figure out how to make Netbeans automatically assign the primary key field 'ID' without having a user to enter it or removing it.

tblSCars - table that I am entering into.
There are no occurrences of field 'ID' anywhere else in the class.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is kind of self-explanatory, you're not specifying what fields to insert into, and the amount of fields you specify in the insert/update query isn't equal to the total amount of fields in the table.

You can specify fields in the following way:

```
insert into tblSCars(Field1, Field2 ... FieldN) VALUES(Value1, Value2 ... ValueN)
UPDATE tblSCars SET Field1 = Value1, Field2 = Value2, etc.
```